# Creating a REST API using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, rest, curl

I’m creating my first API to which if two values are passed, I should get the response in the JSON format. The number  will be passed as parameters by POST. Either using cURL or whatever POST method is available.

Even though this is a very basic one, I would like to know the best practices and the API should be created by model–controller basis. Not just plain PHP.

I have Googled for many REST API tutorials. They were good and I have acquired some knowledge on it.

But I would like to get a sample model of the code so that I can refer to it and build my own, and that sample of course in the standard practice of making a real REST API.

If you ask me what I have tried, it would be really fun, as a beginner, all I could do is this:

```
$num1 = $_REQUEST['num1'];
$num2 = $_REQUEST['num2'];

$total = $num1 + $num2;
echo json_encode($total);
```

Of course this can never be called an API, but still. If I give a POST response to this, I want the response from the REST API as JSON. I should be able to test it by REST console as well so that I get a standard response.

Please do provide me with a very basic but yet a standard RESTful API.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/peej/tonic

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Entirely different from what I asked.Do read their questions before you comment

Comment: @PiyaSharma You have asked someone to make research and write the code for you.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas I Dont think so :)..and sorry if you took it that way.I didnt meant it anyways

Comment: @PiyaSharma: What is this - **"`API should be created by model–controller`"**? Giving an architecture to your API resides in your own hand.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that this is closer to an RPC service than a true REST service.. no?  You just put in some data and get a response, without utilizing the verbs HTTP provides for instance.

Comment: The magic of PHP is the simple ways one can do simple things. If you want to needlessly overcomplicate your code, have a look at Java.

Comment: @Piya Try this https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api  Worked fine

Comment: There is a lot of confusion around what REST really is. What you really want is probably not REST. See here https://medium.com/@trevorhreed/you-re-api-isn-t-restful-and-that-s-good-b2662079cf0e

Comment: roytuts.com/rest-api-crud-example-in-php-mysql/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In your example, it’s fine as it is: it’s simple and works. The only things I’d suggest are:

1. validating the data POSTed
2. make sure your API is sending the `Content-Type` header to tell the client to expect a JSON response:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($response);
   ```

Other than that, an API is something that takes an input and provides an output. It’s possible to “over-engineer” things, in that you make things more complicated that need be.

If you wanted to go down the route of controllers and models, then read up on the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and work out how your domain objects fit into it. Looking at the above example, I can see maybe a `MathController` with an `add()` action/method.

There are a few starting point projects for RESTful APIs on [GitHub](http://www.github.com/) that are worth a look.

Comment: I recommend using the slim 3 framework for writing a REST API in php - worth a look at least :) Mostly because you can add your authentication and ACL as middleware layers (and content negotiation) which is just awesome.

Comment: @JohnHunt or even better: combine an automatic REST API with SlimPHP as described [here](https://tqdev.com/2019-automatic-api-slimphp-3). NB: I'm the author of that post.

Answer (score 17):

Trying to write a REST API from scratch is not a simple task. There are many issues to factor and you will need to write a lot of code to process requests and data coming from the caller, authentication, retrieval of data and sending back responses.

Your best bet is to use a framework that already has this functionality ready and tested for you.

Some suggestions are:

Phalcon - [REST API building](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html) - Easy to use all in one framework with huge performance

[Apigility](http://www.apigility.org/) - A one size fits all API handling framework by Zend Technologies

Laravel [API Building Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785)

and many more. Simple searches on Bitbucket/Github will give you a lot of resources to start with.