# includin php file from url with php

Tags: php, variables, scope, server, include

**i need use this file php Variables post server on url **

```
http://example.com/addData.php   (the other server)
-------------------------------------
$a_player1 = $_POST['a_player1'] = 1;            
$a_player2 = $_POST['a_player2'] = 3;
```

---

```
 htto://srore.com/getdata.php
 -------------------------------------
include("http://example.com/addData.php");
echo $a_player1;
echo $a_player2;
```

**error ???**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a_player1
Notice: Undefined variable: a_player2
```

**php.ini settings then allow_url_include  On**

Comment: If both files are in same folder no need to use ""http://...../test/", just use include("addData.php");

Answer (score 1):

You're including via an absolute URL (which is a hideously bad security problem), which means you're EXECUTING that "remote" php script, and loading its OUTPUT, not the php code it contains.

And if `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, then nothing gets loaded anyways, and no php code will be seen, because that url is never hit.

If that file is on the same server/site as your main one, then do **NOT** use a url, a simple `include('addData.php')` will do.

Comment: thanks you     u  misapprehend 
   http://example.com/addData.php   (the other server)---------------------------------------------------
     htto://srore.com/getdata.php
     -------------------------------------
    include("http://example.com/addData.php");
    echo $a_player1;
    echo $a_player2;


**error ???**

    Notice: Undefined variable: a_player1
    Notice: Undefined variable: a_player2

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is something like a REST API. Something like: [Creating a REST API using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959312/creating-a-rest-api-using-php)